Airflow Custom Timetable Plugin scheduling issue
We have custom job scheduling requirement for Airflow. The requirement is as follows:
Create a custom Timetable class with schedule settings adjustable via Airflow variables to enable configuration changes without redeploying code. This includes varying frequencies for weekdays and weekends during both end-of-month and other periods. Following are 6 variables that needs to be configured-
days_before_eom, days_after_eom, freq_minutes_workweek_eom, freq_minutes_weekend_eom, freq_minutes_workweek_other, freq_minutes_weekend_other
Following is the plugin code developed-
import logging
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.timetables.base import DagRunInfo, DataInterval, Timetable
from airflow.utils import timezone
from pendulum import DateTime

class CustomSchedule(Timetable):
    """Custom Timetable with configurable schedule based on Airflow variables."""

    def __init__(self, days_before_eom: int, days_after_eom: int,
                 freq_minutes_workweek_eom: int, freq_minutes_weekend_eom: int,
                 freq_minutes_workweek_other: int, freq_minutes_weekend_other: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.days_before_eom = days_before_eom
        self.days_after_eom = days_after_eom
        self.freq_minutes_workweek_eom = freq_minutes_workweek_eom
        self.freq_minutes_weekend_eom = freq_minutes_weekend_eom
        self.freq_minutes_workweek_other = freq_minutes_workweek_other
        self.freq_minutes_weekend_other = freq_minutes_weekend_other
        self.next_run = None

    @property
    def summary(self) -> str:
        return f"Custom Schedule"

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return f"This timetable implements a custom schedule based on Airflow variables."

    @property
    def active_runs_limit(self) -> int:
        return 1000  

    @property
    def can_be_scheduled(self) -> bool:
        return True  

    def validate(self) -> None:
        pass  

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "days_before_eom": self.days_before_eom,
            "days_after_eom": self.days_after_eom,
            "freq_minutes_workweek_eom": self.freq_minutes_workweek_eom,
            "freq_minutes_weekend_eom": self.freq_minutes_weekend_eom,
            "freq_minutes_workweek_other": self.freq_minutes_workweek_other,
            "freq_minutes_weekend_other": self.freq_minutes_weekend_other,
            "next_run": self.next_run.isoformat() if self.next_run else None,
        }

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, obj):
        instance = cls(
            days_before_eom=obj.get("days_before_eom", 7),
            days_after_eom=obj.get("days_after_eom", 7),
            freq_minutes_workweek_eom=obj.get("freq_minutes_workweek_eom", 60),
            freq_minutes_weekend_eom=obj.get("freq_minutes_weekend_eom", 1440),
            freq_minutes_workweek_other=obj.get("freq_minutes_workweek_other", 60),
            freq_minutes_weekend_other=obj.get("freq_minutes_weekend_other", 60),
        )
        instance.next_run = DateTime.parse(obj.get("next_run")) if obj.get("next_run") else None
        return instance

    def update_next_run(self, last_run: DateTime = None) -> DateTime:
        now = DateTime.now()
        month_end = now.end_of('month')

        if (now.subtract(days=self.days_before_eom)).start_of('day') <= month_end <= (now.add(days=self.days_after_eom)).end_of('day'):
            freq_minutes = self.freq_minutes_workweek_eom if now.weekday() < 5 else self.freq_minutes_weekend_eom
        else:
            freq_minutes = self.freq_minutes_workweek_other if now.weekday() < 5 else self.freq_minutes_weekend_other

        if last_run:
            next_run = last_run.add(minutes=freq_minutes)
        else:
            next_run = now.add(minutes=freq_minutes)

        self.next_run = next_run
        return next_run


    def infer_manual_data_interval(self, run_after: DateTime):
        """Infer the data interval for manual trigger runs."""
        start_date = run_after  # Start from the provided time
        next_run = self.update_next_run()
        end_date = next_run
        return DataInterval(start=start_date, end=end_date)

    def next_dagrun_info(self, *, last_automated_data_interval: DataInterval, restriction):
        now = DateTime.now()

        if last_automated_data_interval is not None:
            last_start = last_automated_data_interval.start
            next_run = self.update_next_run(last_run=last_start)
        else:
            next_run = self.update_next_run()

        if restriction.earliest is None:
            return None
        elif not restriction.catchup:
            next_start = max(restriction.earliest, now)
        else:
            next_start = (restriction.earliest.add(minutes=1))  # Start from the next minute

        return DagRunInfo(interval=DataInterval(start=next_start, end=next_run))


class CustomTimetablePlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "custom_schedule_timetable_plugin"
    timetables = [CustomSchedule]  # Add the CustomSchedule class to the timetables list

Issue is the above plugin after deployment is not working as expected and DAGs which are using CustomSchedule class are not displaying next_run in Airflow web UI and are not getting scheduled.
Tried developing plugin code and deploying and created sample DAG to use that Plugin but its not working.
